# Tag synonym suggestion [action replay] -> [cheats]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tag-synonyms

I think making [action-replay](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/action-replay) into a synonym of [cheats](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cheats) makes sense since AR is a kind of cheaty thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are only two questions tagged [action-replay](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/action-replay), and those questions are also tagged [cheats](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cheats). Seeing as we don't have tags for [gameshark](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gameshark), [game-genie](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-genie) or any other cheat device that I am aware of, can we not just remove the [action-replay](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/action-replay) tag from those two questions (as it states in the questions specifically that they are looking for AR codes), making the point of the synonym moot?

Comment: With no response to the contrary in 5 days, I've gone ahead and done this (and also improved the questions).

Answer (score 2):

I think we should just kill [cheats](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cheats) and be done with it.  It's not a very good tag.

Answer (score 2):

In these situations we should always opt for more specific tags, rather than tags so generic they're actually useless; so-called "meta tags" such as [cheats](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cheats), which as OrigamiRobot points out isn't exactly our best tag ever. [action-replay](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/action-replay), otoh, is a fine tag.

Comment: I think [tag:action-replay] is just as bad as [tag:cheats]